# How to generate start and end time using Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar, date-format

I am trying to get my startTime and endTime using Calendar so that I can make my url accordingly. I need to make my startTime as yesterday midnight date `2014/09/19 00:00` and endTime for today's midnight date `2014/09/20 00:00`.

So whenever I will run my program, it should generate my startTime as yesterday midnight time and endTime as the midnight of when my program is running.

I have my below code but it gets startTime as `2014/09/20 00:00` and endTime as `2014/09/20 16:00` if I am running my program now.

```
private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Set the hours, mins and seconds to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
    Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
    System.err.println(startTime);

    Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
    endDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());
    System.err.println(endTime);
```

It should do the job (on 2014/09/21 01:50 AM) :

```
2014/09/20 00:00
2014/09/21 00:00
```

Comment: Thanks kraal. In my case it should be oppostie, startTime I am getting as `2014/09/20 00:00` but it should be `2014/09/19 00:00` as today's date for me is September 20th and endTime I am getting as `2014/09/21 00:00` but it should be `2014/09/20 00:00`

Answer (score 0):

## Day Does Not Always Start at 00:00:00

Both question and the other answer assume that the first moment of the day ("midnight") is the time 00:00:00.000. Not always true because of Daylight Saving Time and possibly other anomalies.

## Time Zone

Both question and the other answer ignore the issue of time zone. Determining the date depends on a time zone. Generally best to explicitly specify the intended time zone.

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library to answer the question while addressing the two issues listed above.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTime todayStart = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime tomorrowStart = now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Plus Joda-Time has three classes to represent a span of time: Interval, Period, and Duration.

```
Interval today = new Interval( todayStart, tomorrowStart );
```